# How to query comments only for the current post?

Tags: comments, advanced-custom-fields, wp-comment-query

I am using ACF and my comments have custom fields. I also have custom post type called cars.

What I'm trying to do is to make users comment their average consumption, and then I calculate average consumption for single car.

I did that, and it works well except one part. Average consumption is same for all cars, even each car has different average consumption.

For example:

- Car 1 mpg (28;25;39 - avg  30.6)
- Car 2 mpg (44;50 avg 47)

And when user goes to Car 1, avg should be 30.6 and Car 2 should show 47. Instead each car has same value and it's avg mpg on from all fields (28;25;39;44;50 avg 37.2)

Here is my code. I have followed ACF documentation on getting values from comments

```
 <?php
$args             = array();
$comments_query   = new WP_Comment_Query;
$comments_count   = wp_count_comments();
$comments         = $comments_query->query($args);
if ($comments) {
    foreach ($comments as $comment) {
        $total += get_field('mpg', $comment);
    }
} else {
    echo 'No comments found.';
}
$average = $total / $comments_count->total_comments;
echo round($average, 2);
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

This code is in single-cars.php (custom post type) and it does the calculation but from all comments for all posts, and I want to show calculation for single car.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your arguments for the comment query is empty, so it returns every comment on the planet. You should specify the post ID, to get comments that belong to that post.

```
$args = array(
    'post_id' => get_the_ID(),
);
```

Take a look into the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Comment_Query) page for more information about arguments.